# Adding SSL Certificate to Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate

I am trying to add an SSL certificate to my Nodejs website.

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    const https = require('https');



    const options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/private.key', 'utf8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/certificate.crt', 'utf8'),
        requestCert:true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
     };

var server = https.createServer(options, app);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 443, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on 3000!')
})
```

The app does not throw any error but if I try to connec, I still get the connection is not secure in chrome.

Comment: where did you get the certificate from? is it signed by a know cert authority? or is it just a self generated cert from your computer?

Comment: It was given to me by someone. It is supposed to be a wildcard ssl for the company

Comment: remember that SSL's are also domain specific , i'm assuming it's a wildcard for all subdomain of that domain right? you are also getting this when running on the serve and trying to access it via the domain?

Comment: Is it a wildcard in the sense that it works for `*.yourdomain.com`?

Comment: @Odinn. Yes I am trying to access it using an actual domain like @Aviv Lo is saying `*.yourdomain.com`

Comment: just out of curiosity does this cert work on other subdomains? like, could they have sent you the wrong cert? :) just being optimistic here

Comment: If you just spin up a nginx with this cert on this domain for example will it work fine?

Comment: Added solution below

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to:

```
https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/private.key'),
    ca:fs.readFileSync('./ssl/ca_bundle.crt'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/certificate.crt')
}, app).listen(443);
```

and it worked